# google_drive gem を使ってGoogleDriveの指定したフォルダにアップロードしたい

Tags: ruby, google-drive-sdk

#### 先に結論

railsで、GoogleDriveの指定したフォルダにCSVファイルをアップロードする方法が知りたい

#### 実現したいこと

railsのbatchesにて、google-drive-rubyを利用して日次で作成されるCSVをGoogleDriveの指定したフォルダににアップロードしようと思っています。
（APIはこちら http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/google_drive/2.1.2/GoogleDrive/Session ）

#### 現状

Gemfile

```
gem 'google_drive', '2.1.2'
```

バッチのファイル

```
require "google_drive"
require "csv"
(中略)
def upload_csv
session.upload_from_file(
my_csv,
"#{Date.today.strftime('my_csv_%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}",
convert: true
)
end
```

上記のコードでCSVのアップロード自体はできるのですが、アップロード先のフォルダを選ぶことができず、GoogleDriveのトップ画面に放り込まれるだけ、という状況です。
バッチ専用のフォルダにCSVをアップロードしたいのですが、[API](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/google_drive/2.1.2/GoogleDrive/Session)を見てもその方法が書かれていません。
それどころか、APIのソースを参照すると以下のTODOが。

```
# TODO: Add a feature to upload to a folder.
```

#### 質問したいこと

現状の仕様では、アップロード先のフォルダまで指定することはできないのでしょうか？
もしできないとしたら、他になにか良い方法を知っていたら教えて頂きたいです。
（できるだけ、google_driveのバージョンを落とすなどの方法は用いたくないです。）

#### 補足

ネット上でプログラミングのご質問するのが初めてです。
もし質問の仕方で改善できることろがあったら、そこもご指摘頂ければすごくうれしいです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/59204

Answer (score 2):

> `# TODO: Add a feature to upload to a folder.`

と、ご自身で書かれているように特定のフォルダへのアップロード機能はまだ実装されていないようですので転送が必要なだけであれば`rclone`などの外部プログラムを以下のように`system`などを使い呼び出すのはどうでしょうか？

```
system("rclone ${local_path} #{remote_path}")
```